# Is "moral lesson" grammatically incorrect or redundant?

Tags: redundancy

Someone pointed this out to me earlier today that the correct usage is either *moral* or *lesson*, but not both.

Comment: As @tchrist rightly (and perhaps overzealously..) points out, the phrase is grammatically fine. As to whether it is redundant: well, you can have "math lessons", which *teach you about* math, or "spelling lessons", which *teach you how* to spell, etc. Likewise, you can have "moral lessons" which *teach you about* morals and morality. The lesson doesn't have to be a moral itself (just like the math lesson itself is not math).

Comment: I don't understand why anyone would think it was either incorrect or redundant!

Comment: @curiousdannii Because we often talk about "*the moral of the story*" meaning the ethical lesson delivered, often indirectly, via the narrative.

Comment: @DanBron Sure, but that's clearly a noun, and in this example moral is clearly an adjective.

Comment: @curiousdannii Absolutely. See my first comment and barbecue's answer. But you asked where someone could get the idea that it's redundant: from mixing up the nouns *moral* and *lesson* with the adjective *moral*. Understandable, but ultimately a false criticism.

Comment: @DanBron Hey, I said that already! :)

Comment: @DanBron Okay, but how could they think it was incorrect? Unless they think that it's incorrect to have redundant language, in which case I hope they only speak Lojban.

Comment: @tchrist You did, and better than I ever could.

Comment: @curiousdannii That's a whole 'nother kettle of fish. And one which reeks... (seriously, this pervasive expectation that English is amenable to algebraic reduction baffles and frustrates me. One of my biggest armchair-prescriptivist peeves!).

Answer (score 4):

Not necessarily. The word moral could be an adjective describing what type of lesson is being described. For example, if you are in a science class and there's a lesson about a famous discovery which was associated with scandal and deception, there could be both a *scientific lesson* and a *moral lesson* in the same class.

If you're talking about the "the moral of a story" then, it would probably be redundant to call it a moral lesson, because in this context, moral is understood to be a kind of lesson.

Answer (score 4):

The adjective *moral* primarily means per the OED:

> 1. a. Of or pertaining to character or disposition, considered as good or bad, virtuous or vicious; of or pertaining to the distinction between right and wrong, or good and evil, in relation to the actions, volitions, or character of responsible beings; ethical.
>
>    c. Of knowledge, opinions, judgements, etc.: Relating to the nature and application of the distinction between right and wrong.
>
>    d. *moral sense*: the power of apprehending the difference between right and wrong, esp. when viewed as an innate and unanalysable faculty of the human mind. Similarly *moral faculty*.

Sense 1a would apply to someone’s *moral fibre* or *moral character*. I think the subsense for you is 1c, because a *moral lesson* is a lesson that teaches one about the difference between right and wrong.

Your someone was probably confusing it with the noun *moral*, the one which is sometimes used in the plural like *someone’s poor morals*. They are probably thinking of as the moral of the tale, and so its lesson. The OED gives:

> 2. a. The moral teaching or practical lesson (of a fiction or fable; sometimes, of a real occurrence).
>
>    b. An exposition of the moral teaching or practical lesson contained in a literary composition; that part of a composition (*e.g.* of a fable) which applies or points the moral meaning.

You can see how these are connected, the adjective and the substantive, but to my mind a *moral lesson* is a lesson about right and wrong.

Comment: @DanBron Fixed in the next release. :)

Comment: Let the record show the new beta has passed QA :) I'd give you a second +1 but there's a bug in the SE software which doesn't let me hit the upvote button twice.